# Add URL in web.config and access it in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an URL like this:

> `https://bachqy.desk.info/automalog.aspx?user=""&carid=""`

In my controller, I have an action method that passes two parameters in the above, to redirect the URL. I do not want to hardcode the URL in the controller.

```
public ActionResult NavigateToCar(string userId, string CarID)
{
    return new RedirectResult(
        "https://bachqy.desk.info/automalog.aspx?user="+userId+"&carid="+CarID);
}
```

Inside the controller, in the ActionResult, how can I access the URL from the web.config and pass the following parameters?

How can I pass the URL in the web.config and access the URL and pass the parameters in the controller in ASP MVC?

Comment: [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyUrlFromWebConfig"]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings).

Comment: Add it as an app setting `<appSettings><add name="MyUrlFromWebConfig" value="https://www.example.com"/></appSettings>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings) to read from your "Web.config" file.

To define your URL, you could use something like this in that file:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add 
       name="MyUrlFromWebConfig" 
       value="https://bachqy.desk.info/automalog.aspx?user={UserID}&amp;carid={CarID}" />
</appSettings>
```

(Be sure to escape/encode the `&` as `&amp;` to keep your XML valid)

Later in your code, use:

```cs
public ActionResult NavigateToCar(string userId, string CarID)
{
    var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["MyUrlFromWebConfig"];

    url = url.Replace("{UserID}", Server.UrlEncode(userId));
    url = url.Replace("{CarID}", Server.UrlEncode(carID));

    return new RedirectResult(url);
}
```

(Also be sure to URL-encode the replacement strings to still have a valid URL)

---

I would vote *against* using `{0}` and `{1}` in the URL in the "Web.config" file, and do your own placeholders and replacement (like `{UserID}` in my example above) to be more expressive and not rely on your `String.Format` call to have the correct number and order of format arguments coming from the "Web.config" entry.

Answer (score 0):

in web.config

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="urlPath" value="https://stackoverflow.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

in controller

```cs
var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlPath"];
```